# Split Json Array String in top elements with regex

Tags: json, regex

I'm trying to split the top level elements in a `Json Array` string with regex, but I'm not sure if my solution will capture all cases and all top level elements of the the `Array` `({[^}]*(}\s?)+)`
For example for this array `[{"a":{"a":"a"}},{"b":"b"}]` I would get two elements `{"a":{"a":"a"}}` and `{"b":"b"}`

I have an example here https://regex101.com/r/hAXMvs/1
Is there another way to do capture the top level elements?
My implementation will be in Java, but I don't want to use a library for this.

Comment: _"My implementation will be in Java, but I don't want to use a library for this."_ -- why not?

Comment: I could do this with org.json, but adding this library to the project is not possible, this is why I try adding new libraries

Comment: Why is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is [not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language), and thus cannot be parsed with regex.  You need to use a JSON parser, or write your own parser.